# iOS: creating a background queue for uploading?

Tags: ios6, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, block

I have an app that has five discrete TabControllers.  Each TabController does some work and submits the results to a server.
Could you please give me advice on how to submit data asynchronously using a serial queue?

Should I have one singleton `UploadsService`, which has one `dispatch_queue_t uploadsQueue` reference that each of the five TabControllers accesses and submits blocks of work to?

Or should I have five serial queues (one for each TabController) that live inside each TabBarController and let each TabController use its own serial queue to submit to the server individually?

What I am trying to simulate is a "submit and forget it" approach.  The user just moves effortlessly between the five TabControllers, submitting results to a server frequently.  It's possible that submitting each task might take 20 seconds or so.  I have envisioned one centralized serial queue to guard against concurrency issues, but I am wondering if I need to create a singleton class whose only purpose is just to house a single centralized serial queue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use someone else's hard work (with all the edge cases of network interruptions, app backgrounding, etc). MKNetworkKit solved all of the above (queueing, etc) for me:

https://github.com/mugunthkumar/mknetworkkit

Create shared apiEngine in app delegate:

```
_apiEngine = [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"example.org" apiPath:@"/upload/textdetective/" customHeaderFields:nil];
[_apiEngine useCache];
```

Then where needed:

```
MKNetworkEngine *engine = [delegate apiEngine];
NSString* bundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setValue:bundle forKey:@"bundle"];
[params setValue:version forKey:@"version"];
MKNetworkOperation *op = [engine operationWithPath:@"" params:params httpMethod:@"POST" ssl:YES];
[op setFreezable:YES];
[engine enqueueOperation:op];
```